# the pointer reference point to which object?

Tags: java, pointers, reference

```
String s=new String ("happy");
```

the above example create 2 objects.The pointer reference point to which object?

**RESOLVED**:2 objects created:("happy") and happy.the pointer s point to ("happy").

Comment: thanks for the reminder. will work on that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: how did you find that this line of code was creating two objects?

Comment: i found in effective java book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28java.lang.String%29)

> in other words, the newly created string is a copy of the argument
>   string Based on this text. Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.

So, reference points to newly created String.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable. That means that an instance of String cannot change. You're creating new variable to refer to a different but still immutable String instance.

it allows for changes to the string to branch off the original string in a change list sort of method

```
String s = new String("happy");
```

An  String object ("happy") is created. And the variable `s` refers to that newly created object.